# Maximalize window on Linux Mint 18 xfce not working

Tags: xfce, window-manager

Maximalize window on Linux Mint 18 xfce not working when I use left mouse button and only when my window is on half screen, but when I use right mouse button it works.

Comment: fill a bugreport